# cancel out parts of a formula in CNF (conjunctive normal form)

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

In this image there is a given formula in DNF and CNF. When I check it on Wolfram Alpha I see that it cancel out (E or D) because of (not A or A) which is colored in red. My question is if it is allowed to cancel out (not A or D) because of (not E or E) which is colored in green instead. THX

[image]

Comment: Hint: construct truth-table for this and look if formulas are equal.

Comment: You're allowed to do whatever you want as long as it's mathematically valid.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably useful to note that the [resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_simple_example) can be used to figure out exactly which literals (things like $\neg A\vee D$) may be deduced from the others.

In this case, the resolution rule applied to the clauses $\neg A\vee \neg E$ and $E\vee D$ results in the clause $\neg A\vee D$, which shows that that clause is redundant.

Comment: Resolution rule can change formula. It is used for satisfiability, not for minimizing.

Comment: The resolution rule is actually used for *solving*, or *unsatisfiablility*. In the above case, resolving $\neg A\vee\neg E$ with $E\vee D$ results in $\neg A\vee D$, proving that that clause is redundant.